# "text-transform: uppercase" causes "jumping" during load

Tags: html, css

I have a `h2` element that has the style `text-transform: uppercase`. When I load the page with this element, the container element around the `h2` changes the height during the loading.

This has been the case for Firefox 26 and Chrome 31 (both on OS X).

How to get rid of the "jumping" during the loading?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that because of text-transform the browsers are not able to render all elements on the correct height.

This can be solved by setting `height` on the `h2` element. Doing so, the browser has all the information that is needed. Of course, the height will have to be large enough so that the "end version" after the text transformation fits in.